# How to display native characters properly?

Tags: html, unicode, character-encoding

I am getting unwanted symbols instead of characters of my native language. Instead of (for example) "`ą, ł, ć`" I am getting `�, �, �`.
My 'head' area is like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
```

My webbrowser is Google Chrome version  31.0.1650.63 m.

Can someone help me to overcome this issue, please?

Comment: Where you get that characters? How did you save your HTML file (is it UTF8 as you declare in meta)?

Comment: If you declare the page to be `utf-8`, you have to make sure that it is actually in `utf-8`. You have to save the HTML file in UTF-8 to make this work properly, and ideally you'd want to use UTF-8 with BOM. Also, make sure that all the resources on the page (CSS, JS, ...) are in UTF-8. Very bad things tend to happen if you mix encodings.

Comment: Both of you are very smart on this are. I have checked my file format and it was ANSI. When I changed it to utf-8 everything have started working properly. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your charset header is fine,
in your editor try to convert and save your file as `UTF-8`.

For example in [notepad++](/questions/tagged/notepad%2b%2b)

<kbd>Encoding</kbd> → <kbd>Convert to UTF-8</kbd>

Comment: When saving an HTML file as UTF-8, there is no reason to save without BOM. On the contrary, the BOM gives extra protection by helping browsers to recognize the encoding.

Comment: You should go into details if you make claims against BOM. The BOM has never affected such things. In ancient browsers, it caused some crap at the start of a page, but that’s water under the bridge. Your answer is **wrong** as long as it emphatically says to save **without BOM**. Saving as UTF-8 is the key here, as seen in the comments to the question. Saving without BOM is not needed, and it is a less useful option than saving *with* BOM.